# Find, if they exist, all the values of $k \in \mathbb{R}$ for which the system admits infinitely many solutions

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, diagonalization

Let $A, B \in \mathbb{R}^{3 \times 3}$ be the following matrices:
$$ A=\begin{pmatrix} k+1 & 1 & k \\\ 1 & k & 1 \\\ 0 & -1 & 1 \end{pmatrix} $$
$$ B=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 & k \\\ -1 & 1 & k \\\ 1 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix} $$

Find, if they exist, all values of $k \in \mathbb{R}$ for which the system admits infinitely many solutions:
$$ (A^{2023}B^{2022}-A^{2022}B^{2023})\begin{pmatrix} x_1 \\\ x_2 \\\ x_3  \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} 0 \\\ 0\\\ 0 \end{pmatrix} $$

I have no idea how to solve this, I tried using the fact that if the matrices are similar their determinant is equal. Finding that $det(A)=k^2+k$ and $det(B)=k+3$, then for $det(A)=det(B)$ it must happen that $k=±\sqrt3$. However, I don't know what else to do.

Comment: Let's denote $A^{2023}B^{2022}-A^{2022}B^{2023}$ by $M$, so our system is $M\textbf{x}=\textbf{0}$. Note that $M$ is a $3\times 3$ matrix (why?) and $M\textbf{x}=\textbf{0}$ is a homogeneous system. Now, two hints: (1) rewrite $A^{2023}B^{2022}-A^{2022}B^{2023}$ using properties of matrices, and (2) in terms of determinants, when does a $3\times 3$ homogeneous system like $M\textbf{x}=\textbf{0}$ have infinitely many solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First ,since the matrix $M$ is square ,if has non trivial solution for $Mx=0$ ,then set($M$)=$0$.
Now,
given that $M$=$A^{2022}(A-B)B^{2022}$

From property of determinant,
det($M$)=$0$ means
either $detA=0$ or $detB=0$,or $det(A-B)=0$

Now, $detA=0$ implies $k=0,-1$

$detB=0$ means $k=-3$

Simply compute $det(A-B)=0$
you will get $det(A-B)=(1-k)(1+k)$
hence, $det(A-B)=0$ for $k=1,-1$

hence, $k=0,-1,1,-3$ are required values.

Comment: $A$ and $B$ need not commute, so your expression for $M$ is not right. It should be $M=A^{2022}(A-B)B^{2022}$.

Comment: Yes Thank you I edited